# Need some hint on design a dynamic chart showing wavelength(s) for element

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, plot

I have a very interesting challenge here for my Flex project development.

I now have an experiment wizard which consists of three states.In the first state,the user selects the elements they are interested from the periodic table.

When it comes to the second stage,now we have the elements that the user selected in the first state,and these elements are shown on a list A',the user can select an element from there. Also,I have an xml file that has the intensities and wavelengths for all the elements in the periodic table

Now my challenge is ,I need to build a dynamic image there to show the intensity of the element that the user selects from list A',and also show the neighboring(in terms of the wavelength) 10 elements' intensities on this image too.The X-axis is the wavelength while the Y-axis is the intensity.So the neighboring here basically means the elements has neighboring wavelength values.

All the intensity and wavelength data can be read from the xml file,but I am really stuck here from what kind of component to use and how to make it shown dynamically,so please offer some suggestions please,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarify your flex version 3 or 4.

Read this to use core components

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part7_DataVis_1.html

In other cases you could try to use raw `Graphics` component to draw lines/points/plots etc. as you want or look for some 3rd party components like http://flare.prefuse.org/

Comment: do you have some images if interface you want?

Comment: yes,I do.But I don't know how to post it on here,could you help me,thx.

Comment: @Robert, of course: for images - http://imageshack.us, for source code - http://pastebin.com, for video - http://vimeo.com